# How to identify on console for a remote server what TLS it is providing on an HTTPS endpoint

Tags: networking, openssl, ssl, https

I would like to find a way, to identify what type of TLS a remote HTTPS endpoint is providing, using only "standard" Linux command-line tools.

I would like to know, what type of TLS the server provides: mutual Authentication, Server Authentication, anonymity;
For the used certificate, what the domain, subject and validity is.

I started with the

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443
```

but actually failing to identify what type of TLS it is (the rest I think I would be able to identify on that).

Comment: Note one 'server' can support multiple _sites_ (domains) with different certs which is now common (or even different TLS options though that's rarer), although it's also common to have a single cert covering multiple domains (like stackexchange!). Even a single site can have multiple different certs for different authentication algorithms (usually RSA and ECDSA; in TLS up to 1.2 you _can_ use DSA, and some people used to, but today it's very rare)

Answer (score 0):

That command should give you what you want, for example `openssl s_client -connect google.com:443` includes `TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` in the output.

A more explicit approach to determine which TLS versions are allowed could toggle each version in sequential commands:

```
openssl s_client -tls1_3 -connect google.com:443
openssl s_client -tls1_2 -connect google.com:443
openssl s_client -tls1_1 -connect google.com:443
openssl s_client -tls1  -connect google.com:443
```

Comment: You can't put other options between `-connect host:port` (but in 1.1.1 up you can _leave out_ `-connect` and put `host:port` last). And you don't need the `no` options; specifying any exact version disables all others. Also in 1.0.x the "New, $version, Cipher is" line gave the cipher _format_ version not the protocol version and you needed to look at the "Protocol:" line, but that's rare today. Lastly if server requests client cert _with_ CAnames `s_client` tells you, but to distinguish requesting client cert _without_ CAnames and not requesting at all you need (_much_ longer) `-trace`.